# Error when I run "yarn kbn bootstrap"(kibana install)

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, kibana

Everybody.
I faced trouble when I try to install kibana bootstrap on my win10 os.
I followed this tutorial.
"https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/development-getting-started.html"
When I run "yarn kbn bootstrap", I saw this error.

```
  info [bazel] warning Resolution field "trim@1.0.1" is incompatible with requested version 
  "trim@0.0.1"
  info [bazel] success Already up-to-date.
  info [bazel] INFO: Analyzed target //packages:build (1880 packages loaded, 8122 targets 
  configured).
  info [bazel] INFO: Found 1 target...
  info [bazel] ERROR: F:/work/2021_8/bidrectional/development/kibana-master/packages/kbn-dev- 
  utils/BUILD.bazel:106:11: Action packages/kbn-dev- 
  utils/_validate_tsc_types_options.optionsvalid.d.ts failed: (Exit -1): 
  ts_project_options_validator.bat failed: error executing command bazel- 
  out/host/bin/external/npm/@bazel/typescript/bin/ts_project_options_validator.bat 
  packages/kbn-dev-utils/tsconfig.json ... (remaining 4 argument(s) skipped)
  info [bazel] Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.
  info [bazel] Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
  info [bazel] https://aka.ms/wslstore
  info [bazel] Target //packages:build failed to build
  info [bazel] Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
  info [bazel]
  info [bazel] ERROR: F:/work/2021_8/bidrectional/development/kibana-master/packages/kbn- 
  analytics/BUILD.bazel:89:8 Assembling npm package packages/kbn-analytics/npm_module failed: 
  (Exit -1): ts_project_options_validator.bat failed: error executing command bazel- 
  out/host/bin/external/npm/@bazel/typescript/bin/ts_project_options_validator.bat 
  packages/kbn- 
  analytics/tsconfig.json ... (remaining 4 argument(s) skipped)
  info [bazel] INFO: Elapsed time: 218.882s, Critical Path: 62.52s
  info [bazel] INFO: 217 processes: 65 remote cache hit, 147 internal, 5 local.
  info [bazel]
  info [bazel]
  ERROR [bootstrap] failed:
  ERROR The bazel command that was running failed to complete.
  error Command failed with exit code 1.
  info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

From your system out, it seems you are using windows CMD window for installation.
The official document said in Windows you should run in Git Bash or WSL, and Git Bash is recommended.